# Kotlin - How to be able to run and test function?

Tags: kotlin, junit

I am creating demo code in Kotlin. I am trying so students should be able:

- run function itself
- run test

For example:
If function is created in .kt file, outside of class:

```
fun main(){
    print("Hello world!")
}
```

- it can be run
- but I could not find the way to call it from the test

If the function is inside the class:

```
class Hello {
    fun main(){
        print("Hello world!")
    }
}
```

- the function can be called from the test
- but can not be run - the green "Run" button is not visible.

Question: How to make such a function can be run manually and by test at the same time?

Comment: Is your test written in Java or Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you are writing your tests in Java, because if it's in Kotlin, calling `main` is trivial: `main()`, provided that you have imported the package/in the same package.

Kotlin global functions are compiled into static methods of a class with a name similar to the Kotlin file in which the function is declared, suffixed with `Kt` For example, if the file is called "app.kt", the class name would be `AppKt`. So if you declared `main` in `app.kt`, you would call:

```
AppKt.main();
```

in Java

You can change this name by annotating the Kotlin file with `@JvmName`:

```
@file:JvmName("MyOwnName")
```

Then you can call:

```
MyOwnName.main();
```

in Java.

[See more documentation here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#package-level-functions)